# DRV8313 Charge Pump not working

Tags: driver, brushless-dc-motor

I built up a custom PCB for the DRV8313. I used the schematic from the datasheet (S.15)

The Problem is, that VCP is -0.6V under VM and not +7V over VM. The Power supply has 12V and is adjustable. The V3P3 gives me 3.3V. From S.14 of the datasheet the Problem needs to be undervoltage (V3P3 Operating, charge pump and Output not), but thats not the case. nSleep and nReset are 3.3V from the Arduino and GND is connected from the Arduino and the Power supply. Also if I set nSleep to LOW, the V3P3 Pin gives still 3.3V. The soldering should be fine, since I checked all connections with a multimeter and I soldered a second PCB, where still the same problem occurs.

Anyone an Idea what could be wrong?

[image: PCB]
[image: Schematic]

Comment: Show a schematic.

Comment: Something needs to be oscillating to drive the charge pump. Either one of the inputs, or internally. Read the datasheet (should be linked in the question) to find out what should be oscillating, check if it is, fix it if it isn't.

Comment: The Datasheet is here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8313.pdf I don't see what should oscillating, the logic is internally configured I think.

Comment: @HansPeterLoft: read section 7.3.3 and verify operation of pins and components accordingly

Comment: The components and pins are exactly according section 7.3.3. What I am not sure is, that the Thermal Pad really has ground connection. Can this influence the charge pump? The thermal pad is not internally connected to the other grounds.

Comment: The thermal pad has ground contact, i really dont know what could be wrong. I tried out also different IC's but there still no success.